# Automation Testing using VMSS Agent

Tags: c#, azure-devops, automation, cicd

Does anyone here have tried using VMSS as their agent in ADO and was successful?

I did a POC on this for our company and it seems to be promising. Before we are using a MS Hosted agent. However, the MS agent has limitation as we can't access some certain sites on it due to IP restrictions, thus we are trying to move to using VMSS.

To those who have tried and tested, what would be the Pros and Cons? And is there a better alternative? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Pros**: VMSS Agent can be autoscaled to meet your demands. This elasticity reduces your need to run dedicated agents all the time. Unlike Microsoft-hosted agents, you have flexibility over the size and the image of machines on which agents run. When I queue a build it will create an agent and destroy this agent when done.

**Cons**: You cannot run Mac agents using scale sets. You can only run Windows or Linux agents this way.

Please refer for more information about VMSS agent  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops).

**Reference**:- https://www.reddit.com/r/azuredevops/comments/pjlq9y/automation_testing_using_vmss_agent/